# Why is `f()()` a valid form in quote?

Tags: elixir

```
iex(1)> quote do: f()()
{{:f, [], []}, [], []}
```

While `f()()()` is not:

```
iex(2)> quote do: f()()()
** (SyntaxError) iex:2: syntax error before: '('
```

That is weird since `f()()` does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first expression can be an unquote inside a quote:

```
fun = :hello
quote do
  unquote(fun)(1, 2, 3)
end
```

This will generate a quoted expression that calls `hello(1, 2, 3)`. That's why we only support two levels, because that's all we need. We could make it support n-levels though if we want it in the future.

Comment: So this is actually only useful when used with `unquote`, right? Would it make sense to generate an error or warning if used with something else than `unquote`?

Comment: We already error if you are using it with something other than unquote.

Comment: I mean `quote do: f(:bla)()` could be adjusted to result in an error, but `quote do: unquote(:bla)()` of course not. Or am I not understanding this correctly?